# Why is my program only printing out every other char? C

Tags: c, linked-list, printf

I have created a program to print out a string (ending in '.') in reverse order. The program takes each char and stores it in a linked list in reverse order, then in the main function prints out the linked list. It works, however it prints out every other char.

```
int main (void)
{
    printf("Enter text: ");
    char text;
    textE *nexttext = NULL;
    while(getchar() != '\n')
    {
        text = getchar();
        nexttext = insertchar(nexttext, text);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Don't want to sound rude, because I am sure there are people wanting to help and answer such questions, but for the future this might be useful too ["How do I debug a simple program."](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20do%20i%20debug%20a%20simple%20program)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getchar()` in the `while` loop and the `getchar()` in `text = getchar();` are both taking a character out of the buffer.  You're only seeing every character on output because you're losing every odd character on input.